# Mass Point Geometry with Weights in Vertices

Tags: geometry

The sides of the triangle ABC are AB = 8, BC = 12, and AC = 10.
Let BD be an altitude and CF an angle bisector of the triangle. Let the intersection of BD and F C be E . Find BE : ED and CE : EF . Hint: find first AF : F B (using a theorem about bisectors) and then the lengths of AD and DC .

I got AF:FB to be 5:6 but am having trouble finding AD and DC

Comment: area of triangle $ABC = (BD*AC)/2$

Answer (score 0):

Easy to see that our triangle is acute angled triangle.

Let $AD=x$.

Hence, $8^2-x^2=12^2-(10-x)^2,$ which gives $x=1$.

Thus, $AD:DC=1:9$.

In another hand $AF:FB=AC:BC=10:12=5:6$.

Now, let $G\in{AF}$ such that $GD||FC$.

Thus, $AG:GF=1:9$, which says that
$$BE:ED=BF:FG=12:9=4:3.$$
$CE:EF$ we can find by the same way.

I got $CE:EF=33:2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $AD=x$. Then $DC=10-x$.

$$8^2-x^2=BD^2=12^2-(10-x)^2$$

So $x=1$.

By Menelaus's Theorem,

\begin{align}
\frac{CD}{DA}\cdot\frac{AB}{BF}\cdot\frac{DE}{EB}&=1\\
\frac{6}{5}\cdot\frac{10}{9}\cdot\frac{DE}{EB}&=1\\
BE:ED&=4:3
\end{align}

Also by Menelaus's Theorem,

\begin{align}
\frac{BF}{FA}\cdot\frac{AC}{CD}\cdot\frac{FE}{EC}&=1\\
\frac{9}{1}\cdot\frac{11}{6}\cdot\frac{FE}{EC}&=1\\
CE:EF&=33:2
\end{align}

Comment: Alternative method to find $BE:ED$: as $CE$ bisects $\angle BCD$, we have $BE:ED=BC:CD=12:9=4:3$.